# How to properly assign type to class method in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, class, methods, typescript-typings

During construction of this post, I solved my problem, however I still think, that there might be different approach and I would like to know it..

...

I have a class, where I need to have two methods of the same input and neither of these methods has return value. They just have slightly different bodies.

Since I may add some changes into these methods, I would like to have them typed on one place (opposite to typing each of them individually). It would also look cleaner.

Below I created simplified example code to simulate my problem..

...

I have checked [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html) on typing functions, but I did not find these problems to be reproduced on methods.

Method "meow1" and "meow5" are working ones. But I still expect, that there must be different approach (without assignment operator use).

**How to rewrite "meow4" without assignment operator?**

**Is it possible to leave empty parentheses, if type describes function properly?** ("meow3" and "meow6")

```
type MeowMethodType = (meowText:string) => void;
```

This is what I found in documentation:

```
const meow:MeowMethodType = (meowText:string) => {
    console.log(meowText)
}
```

And this is what I attempted:

```
class Cat {
    // Works, but does not solve my issue..
    meow1 (meowText:string):void {
        console.log(meowText);
    }

    // Error: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
    meow2 (meowText:string):MeowMethodType {
        console.log(meowText)
    }

    // Is such thing possible?
    meow3:MeowMethodType () {
        console.log(meowText)
    }

    // Produces many errors, so I am not sure, how to correct it.
    meow4:MeowMethodType (meowText:string) {
        console.log(meowText)
    }

    // This one works!
    meow5:MeowMethodType = (meowText:string) => {
        console.log(meowText)
    }

    // This one does not..
    meow6:MeowMethodType = () => {
        console.log(meowText)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any tips or clues..

Comment: Soooo what exactly is your question? What are we supposed to answer? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: It sounds like you want interfaces? https://tsplay.dev/WP12kw

Comment: I might have complicated the issue a little.. Thanks for replying, it is mostly, what I wanted. I wanted just something, that will check, if both of my methods still have the same input, so that it will force me to update both of them, if I will be editing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to reduce boilerplate. This is only possible when defining objects and it involves moving the boilerplate elsewhere:

```js
type MeowMethodType = (meowText:string) => void;

interface Meow {
  meow1: MeowMethodType
  meow2: MeowMethodType
}

type Implement<Interface> = Interface & { [k: string]: unknown }

const Cat = {
  meow1(x) {
    //  ^? string
  },

  meow2(x) {
    //  ^? string
  },

  run(distance: number) {

  }
} satisfies Implement<Meow> ;
```

Using `satisfies` with `Implement` lets TS detect other methods like `run` and at the same infer the type of the arguments `x` as `string`.

If you need a class, implementing an interface will only force you to type the methods according to the interface, which is OK: it prevents mistakes when the interface changes, but it does not remove boilerplate.

```js
class Cat implements Meow {
  meow1(x: string) {
    //     ^^^^^^ you are forced to add this
  }

  meow2(x: string) {
    //     ^^^^^^ you are forced to add this
  }

  run(distance: number) {

  }
}
```

In `meow5`, you also neglected that you could remove the type annotation on the parameter

```
meow5:MeowMethodType = (meowText) => {
  //                       ^? string
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshD2B3OwAW8AmAVc0C8UAFALYKJYQAewAXAM7ABOAlgHYDmAlFHgHxQA3eMwwBuAFDi2wCIwBmAQwDG0OEigBvcVCikkARhqwyKdNlzbdZAExG1yCGkw5I4gL6TQkKAEliYABsIUlZgAB4fUNlFFX4CSJl5ZWgAMk0oAG0AayMGFg4AXSMAV1Ys1iRWKA9xJXhWBigAYQVgAHkAIwArHk1LAHp+nR0APQB+Sz1EfUJKbi1hqEHRiZ03ABpJHSnrWfnLHWWoccsNrahGUsIMZgYFVhUjVmLiDtl90-coOlbbuWYIHRfP4giFwvZ+BJagEFHQgS1gFBmCDghBQkD7H1tmQZpRckw2FwscMjsMRuSKVAQPBilAFIxoHJ4IwVBgoMB4HSMGy0LdPpMbLN8fkiQsSUNFhTKdTafTGczWezOQpuezUHy1udLqxrrdgPdHlBnq93n1PjUlDC4c1WtZidikABWGj2UzOXC9EhkCjUbh8e1LCWLYMh0MnTVuIA)

Comment: Seems like, this is what I needed, thanks a lot. I was just afraid, that defining method with assignment operator might have some unwanted effects and it was not allowing me to type my method without it (assignment operator).. as you described "meow5"..

Comment: However are not interfaced meant for mostly public methods? Since my methods should be rather private. It is puzzling me a little.

Comment: You are correct, interfaces are public by design. If you want to force you to keep your private methods in sync with an "interface" you can use an abstract class, although you won't be able to reuse `MeowMethodType` and you will need to make the methods `protected` instead of `private` (which is not necessarily a big deal). Here is an example: https://tsplay.dev/mbE2oN I personally find that simply sharing `MeowMethodType`  like the following is way simpler https://tsplay.dev/mAJ04W this is clearly what I would reach for first, then maybe if the need arises I would use something more verbose.

Comment: Yea, thank you, I also ended up using it with assignment as you show in your second link. May I just ask last thing.. would `meow1 () {}` and `meow2 = () => {}` be **exactly** the same? I just know, that `meow3 = function () {}` differs in `this`. I am not exactly sure, where to find such subtle knowledge.

Comment: I just tested it and `meow1` does not appear as a property of class, while `meow2` does. Will it not cause some "unforseen" issues?

Comment: It is true that methods are non-enumerable and that if you had to turn a `Cat` instance with public methods `meow1 () {}` and `meow2 = () => {}` into a data transfer object by destructuring it or iterating over its properties, you would inadvertently include `meow2` as a function property and not `meow1`. Making them `private` is even worse because TS will hide `meow2` from view but it would still be there. You can remedy that by making it private at runtime: `#meow2 = () => {}`

Comment: I may temper the comment above by saying that if you want to be true to the OO paradigm, `Cat` should be responsible for providing the data transfer object, users should not make assumptions as to how it is structured

Comment: Another thing to consider is that TS compiles `meow2 = () => {}` like this `constructor() {  this.meow2 = x => { } }`, so you would be creating that function each time a new `Cat` is instantiated. This is only a problem if you intend to create a lot of them.

Comment: There is no difference between arrow functions and regular functions in terms of the `this` binding when they are defined in a class: the runtime will bind `this` to the instance in both cases

Comment: Oh, ok, seems like I will stay with `meow2 = () => {}` as property function, since by what you say, it will not cause me any problems. In my real class, I have method `meow`, to which is `meow1` or `meow2` assigned based on some criteria. So that is why I think, they may/should be private, because they are called from the *preffered* and *real* `meow`. Thanks a lot, I am marking your answer as a solution. O:-)